# How to get rid of garbage data in blend file

Tags: python, append, data-blocks

I'm having a problem that by appending collections from scene to scene (or shot to shot) the blend files are inflating in size (well over 1GB already), although they contain more or less the same content. I found a ton of objects, images and materials in the blend file (Outliner>Blender File) which are not visible in the view layer nor viewport but only in the Blender file, and are often duplicates or materials and images from deleted objects or hierarchies. Purging does not get rid of them, and they are simply too many to figure out manually which ones are needed an what is garbage data. There is only 1 scene and 1 view layer in the blend file.

Is there a way with python to get rid of this unused garbage data-blocks?
Example here:
[image]

Comment: Sorry, just to confirm, you already tried clearing everything from the Orphan Data panel, and that is not satisfactory?

Comment: Yes, I already used the purge button from the Orphan Data panel, but there is still a lot of garbage left. To get startet I used python to find objects using certain materials which I was sure were not in use anymore (because I deleted the objects using them), and found a couple of objects only showing up in the Blender File view (after purging!). But doing that for 100s of objects is too tedious.

Comment: Yeah, ok. Just checking. I'm not sure about the python code - I'll look into it, but I'll admit it's not my forté, so no promises. I'll upvote so hopefully someone better at .bpy can figure it out.

Comment: It almost seems like the Objects like "Grate slope gratecut.002" are still existing somewhere, since the Mesh Data and Materials aren't being orphaned to purge like usual. Is there anything nonstandard about how the scenes/shots themselves are set up? You mentioned your use case is appending collections from scene-to-scene, and I noticed that your results for the Blender File search don't indicate a scene the object could be under. If the object were truly trashed it wouldn't show up under those results, only the remnants in Orphan Data.

Comment: Nothing unusual, assets are linked or appended into scenes for shot construction. At times assets are appended from another shot to get the exact last state (pose etc.) for continuity. I noticed that by doing that, sometimes objects show up in the appended data which was deleted in  shot from which it is appended from (sometimes by deleting a hierarchy in the outliner). That's how I noticed that something was wrong (besides growing filesizes) and started to investigate. Unfortunately I don't have enough insight in Blenders data structure to know how to identify and delete such objects.

Answer (score 2):

Finally I found a way do deal with this issue: Atomic Data Manager add-on for Blender by remington creative (free add-on):

https://remington.pro/software/blender/atomic/

It seems that I am not the only one who noticed that something is fishy here.